# Deshabilitar button y select en un modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal

tengo un problema tengo una **function** la cual llena los campos de un modal lo que quiero es que cuando `$('#estatus').val(d[7]);` sea igual a 0 y 1 se habilite el **select** `$('#estatus').val(d[7]);` y el **button** actualiza datos y cuando sea 2 o 3 estos mismos el **select** y el **button** se deshabiliten  (este es mi código)

```
function agregaForm(datos){

   d=datos.split('||');

    $('#id').val(d[0]);
    $('#año').val(d[1])
    $('#s').val(d[2]);
    $('#reporte').val(d[3]);
    $('#edad').val(d[4]);
    $('#nombre').val(d[5]);
    $('#apellido').val(d[6]);
    $('#estatus').val(d[7]);
    $('#cu').val(d[8]);
    $('#nuevacu').val(d[9]);



 var c= $('#estatus').val(d[7]);

 if ((c=="1")&&(c=="0")) {

    $("#actualiza").disabled= false;
    $("estatus").disabled = false;

 }
 else{

    $("#actualiza").disabled= true;
    $("#estatus").disabled = true;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `$('#estatus').val(d[7])` setea el valor de ese elemento, y retorna la instancia jQuery del elemento. Debés usar en el `if` la función sin enviar el parámetro para que retorne el valor asignado al elemento: `$('#estatus').val()`:

```
var b = $('#estatus').val();
if ((b == "1")&&(b == "0")) {
    $("#actualizadatos").disabled= false;
    $("estatus").disabled = false;
} else{
    $("#actualizadatos").disabled= true;
    $("#estatus").disabled = true;
}
```

Por otro lado, tienes otros dos errores:

Dado que más arriba asignaste el valor d[7] al elemento, no hay necesidad de volver a extraer el valor. Podés usar directamente la variable d[7] en la cláusula if. Además, el atributo disabled de un elemento no funciona con `true` o `false`, sino que, si el navegador encuentra el atributo (independientemente de su valor), deshabilitará el elemento, por lo que debes agregarlo o quitarlo de forma dinámica. El código corregido es el siguiente:

```
// var b = $('#estatus').val();
// ^^ Ya no es necesario
if ((d[7] == "1")&&(d[7] == "0")) {
    $("#actualizadatos").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("estatus").removeAttr('disabled');
} else{
    $("#actualizadatos").attr('disabled','true');
    $("#estatus").attr('disabled','true');
}
```